# What is the easiest way to build a string if i have the character and length

Tags: c#, string

In C#, as inputs i have:

Letter: "A"
Length: 5

and i want to output:

"AAAAA"

Is there a more elegant way of doing this besides loop?

Comment: the answer is obvious new String, why did you ask? this question is for real? :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use string constructor: `new string('A', 5);`

Answer (score 2):

You could just just the [character repeating String constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsa4321w.aspx) to create the String.

```
Console.WriteLine(new String('A', 5));
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes:

```
String st = new String('A', 5);
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsa4321w.aspx).